# Tkinter: How to pass arguments from entry to function (and glitch in exiting)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working on a login page in Tkinter for fun, but I am unable to make a function that checks the entries and compares them to a specific input. Also, the code adds a messagebox and calls a function every time I exit the window.

My code is:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()
root.title("Login")



def makeUname(d):
    if messagebox.askyesno("Submit?", "Is this correct?"):
        global password
        username = uname.get()
        uname.grid_forget()
        return password

def makePasswd(d):
    if messagebox.askyesno("Submit?", "Is this correct?"):
        global username
        password = uname.get()
        passwd.grid_forget()
        return username

def button():
    makeUname("")
    makePasswd("")
    quitbutt.grid_forget()


uname = Entry(root)
uname.grid(row=1, column=1)

passwd = Entry(root, show="*")
passwd.grid(row=2, column=1)

quitbutt = Button(root, text="Login", command=button)
quitbutt.grid(row=3, column=1,  columnspan=2, sticky='nesw')


root.mainloop()

makeUname("")
makePasswd("")

if(username == "username" and password == "password"):
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Sorry, this isn't programmed yet.")
else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Nope", "Nope. Nice try.")
```

Can someone help me with my code? Should I use a different setup or method?

Comment: all code after `mainloop()` is executed after you close window - and you have `messagebox.showwarning()` after `mainloop` so you see `messagebox` after you close window.

Comment: `uname.get()` in your functions gives you text from `Entry` - you have to only use `print(uname.get())` to see it.

Comment: in function you use `global username` but you assign value to `password` - it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was many problem so I changed all to make it simpler.

I added comments in code to explain some elements.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

# --- functions ---

def button():
    # use global variable (instead of local variables) 
    # to keep username, password outside function and keep after closing window
    global username
    global password

    username = uname.get()
    password = passwd.get()
    #print('button:', username, password)

    if username == "username" and password == "password":
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Sorry, this isn't programmed yet.")
        root.destroy() # close window
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Nope", "Nope. Nice try.")
        # window still open

# --- main ---

# default values at start 
# Someone can exit window without using Button
# and it would not create this variables in button()
username = ""
password = ""

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")

uname = Entry(root)
uname.grid(row=1, column=1)

passwd = Entry(root, show="*")
passwd.grid(row=2, column=1)

quitbutt = Button(root, text="Login", command=button)
quitbutt.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nesw')

# start program (start engine, display window, (re)draw widgets, handle events, get events from system (keyboard, mouse), send events to widgets)
root.mainloop()

# after closing window this variables still have values from window
print("after mainloop:", username, password)
```

Comment: Sorry that there were so many problems - I am a total amateur at this and I am very thankful for this. Now I can make the actual thing I was going to make after the login.